# Audience Segmentation question - Choosing the population to judge a new model through an A/B test

Tags: churn, marketing

Would really appreciate your thoughts on the below problem.

There was an old model which gave an output of 10M emails of people who are expected to churn along with their churn propensity.
A new model was built which gave out 5M emails of people who are expected to churn along with their churn propensity.
You can only send 1M emails on the whole. So basically you get to choose 1M email IDs of the total population you have from the above two ouputs.
There is an intersection between the two population ouputs.

Now, how will you do an A/B test to judge the performance of the new model?
How will you choose the population split for test vs control?

*P.S. I'm new to this community and hence I apologize if I made any mistakes while providing the details of the question.*